# Python console in pycharm sometimes writes results to top of console thus clashing with earlier content

Tags: pycharm

When using *Execute Selection in Console* and the python console is not presently active then a new internal *repl* session is started and this works fine.

However after running the a few times `pycharm` may become confused and it will start adding new content at the *top*  of the console window instead of appending to the bottom

[image]

This makes finding the results of the latest execution difficult: they are hidden below the older content.

Anyone found a way to avoid getting into this confused mode for pycharm console?

**Update**  One triggering condition appears to be when re-running an entire script with the `python console` already open.

Comment: Can't reproduce it, did you notice any specific steps required to trigger the issue?

Comment: @PavelKarateev  I have tried to guess what are the conditions to trigger this but not yet. Will update here if I can discover it.

Comment: @PavelKarateev  Updated the question: one triggering conditions seems to be to re-run an entire script via the `Run|Run` menu item when the `python console` is already open and already had content / results in it.